# Springer fibers in exceptional types

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Cohomology ring of Springer fibers can be calculated for ADE types and a subregular nilpotent. Also for classical types cohomology ring of Springer fibers can be calculated for two-block nilpotents. My question is, are there Springer fibers in any exceptional types, which are not subregular, where one might hope to calculate the cohomology ring? (So describing the components of the Springer fiber and intersections of components would be helpful.) Maybe there are some analogs of two-block or hook Springer fibers for exceptional types, where one might hope to calculate their cohomology ring?

Comment: Did you look at De Concini Lusztig Procesi? They give the most detailed structure known of Springer fibres in exceptional type.